# Angular JS simple dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, code-injection

I want to inject a javascript object into my controller.
I decide to use "value" approach. This works:

```
//define a module
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

//create a value object as "defaultInput" and pass it a data.
mainApp.value("defaultInput", 5);
...

//inject the value in the controller using its name "defaultInput"
mainApp.controller('CalcController', function($scope, CalcService, defaultInput) {
   $scope.number = defaultInput;
   ...
```

But as soon as i use Inline Array Annotation for controller, the `defaultInput` argument become underfined while controller instantiation:

```
mainApp.controller('CalcController', ['$scope','CalcService', function($scope, CalcService, defaultInput) {
```

I dont want to refuse of inline instantiation since it is recommended way accroding documentation, but can't find how to inject my object in this case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to inject dependency `defaultInput`

```
mainApp.controller('CalcController',['$scope','CalcService','defaultInput',//<--inject here
   function($scope,CalcService,defaultInput) {
```